# Magento sort product list with Isotope or Masonry

Tags: javascript, php, magento, jquery-isotope, jquery-masonry

I want to sort my products in the list.phtml, I want to have one big product in the right, I want to be like in this image.

[image]

My HTML code is like this:

```
<ul class="products-grid row four-columns first last odd">
<li class="item type-1 quick-view-container">
<div class="quick-view-data-container"></div>
<div class="inner">
<div class="image-box">
<div class="product-labels-wrapper clearfix">
<a class="product-image" title="" href="tori-tank.html">
<div class="ajax-media-overlay">
<div class="actions clearfix two-items">
<button class="btn btn-default btn-quickview btn-ajaxkit-quick-view AjaxKit-quick-view-link" title="QuickView" data-id="418">
<span class="link-wishlist-wrapper">
</div>
</div>
<div class="description-box">
</div>
</li>
<li class="item type-1 quick-view-container">
<li class="item type-1 quick-view-container">
<li class="item type-1 quick-view-container">
<li class="item type-1 quick-view-container">
<li class="item type-1 quick-view-container">
<li class="item type-1 quick-view-container">
<li class="item type-1 quick-view-container">
<li class="item type-1 quick-view-container">
<li class="item type-1 quick-view-container">
<li class="item type-1 quick-view-container">
<li class="item type-1 quick-view-container">
</ul>
```

Thank you

Comment: Create Fiddle or provide code...

Comment: hmm I don't have a code all I can put here is only the html structure

Comment: to have the same structure like in that image

Comment: yes like that but how it can be like in my image?

Comment: Check my answer below, hope it helps :)

Comment: Try this : https://jsbin.com/loronibali/2/edit?output

Comment: Sunil Gehlot this is not help me anymore, I need the script to be like what I have in the image, and need to identify the third or four item in my html with javascript, you know everything about magento? anyway thank you so much for your efforts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tLk8emnz/)

**HTML**

```
<ul id="container" class="cols">
    <li class="box one"></li>
    <li class="box two"></li>
    <li class="box one"></li>
    <li class="box three"></li>
    <li class="box two"></li>
    <li class="box five"></li>
    <li class="box one"></li>
    <li class="box two"></li>
    <li class="box six"></li>
    <li class="box three"></li>
    <li class="box two"></li>
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
#container {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 700px;
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
    margin: 2em auto;
}
.cols {
    -moz-column-count:3;
    -moz-column-gap: 3%;
    -moz-column-width: 30%;
    -webkit-column-count:3;
    -webkit-column-gap: 3%;
    -webkit-column-width: 30%;
    column-count: 3;
    column-gap: 3%;
    column-width: 30%;
}
.box {
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
    list-style:none;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.box.one {
    height: 200px;
    background-color: #d77575;
}
.box.two {
    height: 300px;
    background-color: #dcbc4c;
}
.box.three {
    background-color: #a3ca3b;
    height: 400px;
}
.box.four {
    background-color: #3daee3;
    height: 500px;
}
.box.five {
    background-color: #bb8ed8;
    height: 600px;
}
.box.six {
    background-color: #baafb1;
    height: 200px;
}
```

Comment: can you make this to be the same like in my page? and if you take a look on my html code I can't add classes because is on magento, the html structure will be the same like there