# Grid view (same width / different heights) - 3 columns | CSS

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make a grid view with 3 columns using css.
I have the 2 column system working with the following code, but I can't seem to get it correct for 3 columns:

```css
#container{background-color:#aaa;margin: 0 auto;height:500px; width: 200px;}
.box{background-color:white;
  border:1px solid black;
  margin: 2%;
  width:45%;
  display:block;
  float:left;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.box:nth-child(2n + 0) { float: right; }
```

```html
<div id='container'>
  <div class='box' style="height:70px; background-color: red;">1</div>
  <div class='box' style="height:130px; background-color: grey;">2</div>
  <div class='box' style="height:90px;">3</div>
  <div class='box' style="height:86px; background-color: orange;">4</div>
  <div class='box' style="height:110px; background-color: green;">5</div>
  <div class='box' style="height:40px;">6</div>
</div>
```

Here's the jsfiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/jfnvt9o3/

**Is there a way to achieve the following with only css, and if so, how?**

[image: example]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Magento sort product list with Isotope or Masonry](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36745698/magento-sort-product-list-with-isotope-or-masonry)

Comment: @SunilGehlot it's not a duplicate, because that solution doesnt go through the rows as shown in the image above, in the solution provided there, the first column will consist out or box 1-2-3, column 2 will be 4-5-6 and column would be 7. This is not what I want

Comment: You need the divs in order in your HTML code?

Comment: @blonfu yes I want it to begin at 1 and increase going through rows. So the first line would be 1 - 2 - 3 and the second row is 4-5-6, and so on.

Comment: ok, then forgot my answer. I don't delete because maybe is helpful for any other

Answer (score 6):

If you can reorder your HTML there is a solution with multiple column. In other case I think is not possible without JavaScript.

```css
#container {
  background-color: #aaa;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 500px;
  width: 500px;
  -moz-column-count: 3;
  -webkit-column-count: 3;
  column-count: 3;
  -moz-column-gap: 10px;
  -webkit-column-gap: 10px;
  column-gap: 10px;
}

.box {
  background-color: white;
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 10px 0;
  display: inline-block;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div id='container'>
  <div class='box' style="height:70px; background-color: red;">1</div>
  <div class='box' style="height:86px; background-color: orange;">4</div>
  <div class='box' style="height:130px; background-color: grey;">2</div>
  <div class='box' style="height:110px; background-color: green;">5</div>
  <div class='box' style="height:90px;">3</div>
  <div class='box' style="height:40px;">6</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

there's also a way using **flexboxes** (though you can implement it without flexboxes as well) but you need to tweak your HTML a bit: **[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/jfnvt9o3/4/)**

```
<div id='container'>
  <div class="column">
    <div class='box' style="height:70px; background-color: red;">1</div>
    <div class='box' style="height:86px; background-color: orange;">4</div>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <div class='box' style="height:130px; background-color: grey;">2</div>
    <div class='box' style="height:110px; background-color: green;">5</div>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <div class='box' style="height:90px;">3</div>
    <div class='box' style="height:40px;">6</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#container{background-color:#aaa;margin: 0 auto;height:500px; width: 200px; display:flex;}
.box{background-color:white;
  border:1px solid black;
  margin: 2%;
  width:94%;
  display:block;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.column{
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:column;
  width:33%;
}
```

Comment: that is exactly the same as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36745698/magento-sort-product-list-with-isotope-or-masonry and I can't achieve this seeing I call in my data through date created

Comment: @blonfu sorry, fixed it

Comment: @Borni you can easily write a function to create this structure out of any data given

Answer (score 0):

Try this javascript library - there is no proper (cross browser) css-only solution:

http://masonry.desandro.com/

You can try css columns too:

https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/c/columns/

Comment: Hiya thanks, I had already seen that but I'm looking for a solution that does not involve jquery. I'm making my project in angularjs but the angularjs solutions are not good (in my opinion) hence me trying to look for a css methode only.

Answer (score 0):

Cant you just make the divs of the same row to have the same height? If they have the same height(same fo the divs of the same row), it should look like this:

```css
#container {
  background-color: #aaa;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 500px;
  width: 200px;
}
.box {
  background-color: white;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 2%;
  width: 45%;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.box:nth-child(2n + 0) {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<div id='container'>
  <div class='box' style="height:130px; background-color: red;">1</div>
  <div class='box' style="height:130px; background-color: grey;">2</div>
  <div class='box' style="height:90px;">3</div>
  <div class='box' style="height:90px; background-color: orange;">4</div>
  <div class='box' style="height:110px; background-color: green;">5</div>
  <div class='box' style="height:110px;">6</div>
</div>
```

Comment: As stated above, the divs do not have the same height. This is not what I'm looking for.

Comment: Ok, if thats what you ask, im on it :)