# Grid layout collapsing

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I want to make a grid system with only CSS such that

1. Grid can be of arbitrary height (same width) and when a grid overflows, it is stacked vertically and underneath the first grid of the previous row, regardless of the height of other grids.
2. When the window reaches a certain size, the grid system collapses and only stacks vertically.

[image: description]

After looking for a while, I found a [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37831506/grid-view-same-width-different-heights-3-columns-css) for my first requirement using the flexbox layout. However, I just can't figure out how to make them stack vertically once they collapse since in my solution `d1` and `d4` are part of the same column which make them next to each other. Any thoughts on that?

Edit: My code is basically [this](https://jsfiddle.net/jfnvt9o3/4/)

```css
#container {
  background-color: #aaa;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 500px;
  width: 200px;
  display: flex;
}

.box {
  background-color: white;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 2%;
  width: 94%;
  display: block;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.column {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 33%;
}
```

```html
<div id='container'>
  <div class="column">
    <div class='box' style="height:70px; background-color: red;">1</div>
    <div class='box' style="height:86px; background-color: orange;">4</div>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <div class='box' style="height:130px; background-color: grey;">2</div>
    <div class='box' style="height:110px; background-color: green;">5</div>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <div class='box' style="height:90px;">3</div>
    <div class='box' style="height:40px;">6</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: In the future you'll be able to use [`display: contents`](https://css-tricks.com/get-ready-for-display-contents/) (and order, [here with Grid layout](https://codepen.io/PhilippeVay/pen/VxqaLo?editors=1100)) but for now and in the near future no Edge support and very recent Blink support [caniuse](https://caniuse.com/#search=contents)

Answer (score 0):

Try learning media query https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp. It can help you stack them vertically when you reached a certain width.

Comment: Stacking them isn't the problem. It's more about changing the way to stack them once reaching a breakpoint.

Comment: isn't that the same ? you can use media query to stack them in a different way when you reached a certain breakpoint ?